# HTML / CSS / jQuery- Make inline-block divs fully cover their containing div, in spite of their container being contained by a smaller div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make some icons inside a menu overflow to the right and be revealed when the user drags the menu handle to the right. The problem is that the inline-block divs don't want to cover the whole space of their container, because their container is on its turn contained by a smaller div (which seems to delimit how far the icons go to the right).

In the images, the div highlighted in blue (by the chrome dev tools) is the container of the icons. For some reason, the lines don't go to its full width and stay condensed on the left, delimited by the menu div.

I hope this wasn't very confusing. Can anyone help me, please? How do I make the icons fully occupy the width of their container? Thanks a lot!

[image: Descriptive image 1]

[image: Descriptive image 2]

Code:

The css of the icons, set by jQuery

```
$("." + localIcons[iconToRender].name).css({
    "display": 'inline-block',
    "width": box_width,
    "height": box_height,
    "border-radius": '5px',
    "margin": box_margin / 2
 });
```

The icons container:

```
// appended to the body: <div class="box-menu"> <div class="box-menu-icon-container"> </div> </div>

$( ".box-menu").css({
    "position": 'absolute',
    //Remember that the width of the menu is set by dragging the jQuery handle, so here I just set a minimum width equal to the size of the handle
    "width": box_menu_handle_width,
    "min-width": box_menu_handle_width,
    "max-width": box_menu_max_width,
    "height": box_menu_height,
    "left": 0,
    "top": '50%',
    "margin-top": -( box_menu_height / 2 ),
    "background-color": box_menu_color,
    "border-radius": '0px 5px 5px 0px',
    "overflow": 'hidden'    
  });

  $(".box-menu-icon-container").css({
    "height": box_menu_height - 60,
    "width": box_menu_max_width
  });
```

Comment: Why did you delete your previous post and then repost?

Comment: Because I did a major edit to it, and the people who had already seen it, and skipped because I didn't provide any code, wouldn't come back to help me. Since I almost doubled the size of the thread I guess I should as well start fresh. Besides, I didn't get any answers previously. (to the point, I mean.)

Comment: The reason you didn't get answer was in part because you did not post code. Usually, if people ask for code, they will come back to see if you posted code. You can alert them that you posted code by commenting back to them using the `@` syntax in a comment. So if I put a name, such as yours, @MarcosPereira, then it sends a comment alert to them. Any edit will bump the question up on the "active" tab, but deleting and reposting erases all the history (comment, answers, etc.) otherwise. Not a good practice.

Comment: Sorry then. Won't do it again :/ Too bad I'm not getting any answers either way... @ScottS

Comment: What you really need to provide is the final html code that the jquery produces, and the final css code that is driving the display of it. That is really the only way it can be debugged (and why you are not getting any answers). Even more helpful would be to produce a test case of the issue in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that others can mess with the code to try and fix it. Images can only communicate so much, and don't reveal the whole context of what may be interacting to cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the `box-menu-handle` being `float: right` which is keeping the icons constrained to what is intended to be the menu space. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/p3y5E/2/).

In other words, its designed to not allow the icons to "infiltrate" past the space allotted for the menu, which is defined by that handle that controls the menu width.

If you really wanted to override it, you would need to eliminate that `float: right` and rather absolutely position the handle to the right. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/p3y5E/3/). I don't know how all that will interact with other aspects of the menu script, but it would allow the icons to "overlap" the space they are supposed to and intrude past the menu handle (which seems to be what you desire, though I do not know why).

Comment: I was going to (at a big mental cost ^^) try to setup a jsfiddle, after your comment. But I see that you answered anyway, and for that, I tip my hat to you, Sir! I'll test some stuff and get back to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I took on the mental cost to try to figure out what you were experiencing. It is usually best not to leave that in the hands of those of us who want to help, as such preparatory work should be in the hands of the one asking the question, so that those answering can just focus on the issue (not on how to recreate the issue). I hope my answer helped.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the float: right and absolutely positioning the handle instead, thank you so so so so much!